# How to install beautiful soup for anacadona?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed anacondas and am able to use jupyter notebook as well as pandas.

But I have only done this through a tutorial.

How do I install beautiful soup? Do i put this in the command prompt? In jupyter notebook?

What do I type?

What do i import as a package?

Am totally lost, thanks

AND THE ERROR I GET IS: ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\skull\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to install beautiful soup is using conda by typing the following into your command prompt:

```sh
conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4
```

Then in your python code, you can import it like so:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried this and get this error during my code -

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\skull\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)

Comment: Make sure you properly capitalise BeautifulSoup (Note that the B and S are capital letters)